# Metodo alternativo para abrir otro formulario

Tags: c#

Un saludo para todos, quería ver si existe algún método alternativo para abrir un segundo formulario desde el principal.
Pongo el código y a continuación explico lo que estoy buscando

```
FrmContas_pagar Abre = FrmContas_pagar.GetInstancia();
Abre.MdiParent = this;
Abre.Show();
int selecc = Abre.dtgPagos.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
if (selecc == 0)
{
    Abre.Close();
}
```

Esta acción la realiza en el evento *load* del formulario principal para ver si en el segundo formulario existen cuentas para pagar en el día de hoy. Si es así, me abre el formulario y si no hay lo cierra.

El problema es que como siempre lo abre con `Abre.Show()` y si no hay registros seleccionados en segundo formulario lo cierra automáticamente.
Produce una especie de pantallazo que, visualmente, es desagradable al abrir y cerrar de inmediato.

¿Existe algún método para evitar este pantallazo u otro código alternativo a `Show()`?

Quiero agradecer de antemano el tiempo dispensado.

Comment: Tu problema esta en la logica... para que lo mostras si no sabes si lo necesitas? primero deberias comprobrar que lo necesitas, y luego abrirlo... El metodo para abrir un form es el correcto y el que hay...

Comment: @gbianchi, perdona mi ignorancia, pues soy autodidacta en programación y voy aprendiendo a base de probar y probar. ¿Como haria para comprobar si necesito el formulario sin abrirlo?. Ya que primero se carga el formulario principal y despues abre el segundo para hacer está comprobación, pero si no lo abro no puedo saber si el datagridview tiene filas seleccionadas. Si tienes alguna idea, te agrdeceria que me dieras un empujón para intentar solucionalo. Gracias JoaquimVL

Comment: No hay nada porque disculparse.. algo no te quedo claro de mi comentario?

Comment: De paso por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: Joaquin tu pregunta es justamente eso que pusiste en tu comentario. Para eso, tenes una clase para ver cuantas facturas hay? como cargas tu grilla?

Comment: @gbianchi, El dtgPagos se carga desde un Store procedure donde evalua la fecha.

Comment: Saludos,  como te indica @JoaquimVolart  lo ideal seria que antes de llamar al formulario llames al método para verificar si hay pagos, supongo que el método lo tienes dentro del formulario así que seria mejor sacarlo a una clase independiente, pero también lo puedes dejar en el formulario y lo llamas luego de declara la variable del formulario y solo llamas a show si te devuelve que hay pagos. ejem: var form = new FormPagos(); if(form.TienePagos(/*Aquí verificas con la db si hay pagos pendientes*/))  form.show();

Comment: Joaquin, si, ok, pero donde? como armas ese formulario?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es hacer un método en el formulario pricipal, donde llames el mismo procedimiento almacenado que tienes en el segundo formulario, para así evaluar si tienes facuras pendientes

Comment: Antes de nada, quiero agradecer enormemente vuestro esfuerzo y colaboración para ayudarme. Encontré una solución e iba a compartirla con vosotros, pero al intentar responder a mi propia pregunta, me deparé con la sorpresa que parece ser que mis comentarios molestaron a algunos compañeros, por lo que decide dejarlo como está.
Repito gracias a todos.
JoaquimVL

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te quedaría mejor así, de esta forma solo muestras el formulario si select es diferente de 0

```
    **FrmContas_pagar Abre = FrmContas_pagar.GetInstancia();
    Abre.MdiParent = this;
    int selecc = Abre.dtgPagos.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (selecc != 0)
    {
        Abre.Show();
    }**
```

Comment: Para esto, abria que ver primero en que punto cargo dtgPagos...

Comment: @Macx, si lo pongo asi no lo abre, pues no ha evaluado si el datagridview, tiene filas seleccionadas

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el fallo está en abrir un formulario, solo para saber si hay cuentas pendientes.

Esa lógica que te da las cuentas pendientes (que es la que tienes que estar usando en tu segundo formulario para rellenar la DataGridView), debería poder invocarse desde el primero formulario.

En el primer formulario:
1º Consultas cuentas pendientes
2º Si cuentas pendientes > 0 Abres formulario para mostrarlas

Espero te sirviera de ayuda